# How to create modular in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to create a modular to create a controller and a model.

Of course, the model is pre-created.

```
php artisan module:make-controller Admin\ReportController Report --model=Report
```

I see this message

> The "--model" option does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you used [nWidart Modules](https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules), so the answer is you can not use `--model` option because nWidart Modules doesn't support that option/parameter. You need run another command to create a model, an example:

```
php artisan module:make-model Report Admin
```

`Report` is model name, and `Admin` is module name

[check it out](https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules/v6/advanced-tools/artisan-commands) for more module commands